# Why is my mail function not working? PHP

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to set some PHP, where if a user enters in their email address; they send an email to the organization.

Here's my html

```
<input type="text" name="email" size="20" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

And here's my PHP script

```
$email = $_POST['email'];

mail('randomEmail@gmail.com', 'This is a Subject', 'This is the body of the email', 'From $email');
```

I have a real email address that I'm using for this code. But it won't send it to the email that I want; what am I doing wrong? I am also working on a local server as well. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Why do I think that $email won't interpolate

Answer (score 2):

The format of your `From` header is incorrect. You're missing the colon `:`.

```
mail('randomEmail@gmail.com', 'This is a Subject', 'This is the body of the email', 'From: $email');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
```

for more help:http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp